# Variable HTF indicator resolution based on chart resolution

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to plot a higher timeframe ema. The timeframe that the ema uses should be dependent on the current chart resolution.

I calculate the current chart resolution like this:

```
chart_res = timeframe.period
```

Then I use chart_res in order to determine what the HTF value should be for the ema:

```
res = chart_res == "1" ? "15" : chart_res == "15" ? "240" : "D"
```

^ causes error
Then finally, I create the HTF ema like this:

```
htf_ema = security(tickerid, res, ema)
```

The ema works as expected when I manually enter the timeframe it's supposed to use as a "res" input. However, using the code above for determining throws an error.

Can someone please explain to me why I'm getting this error and how I can accomplish this task, which I thought should be pretty simple?